# HTML special characters in UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am getting data in JSON, and it has HTML formatted text (With special characters). I am parsing it, and I need to display it in a UITableView as the rows.

Can you help me how to do it?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can You elaborate question?
One of the simple way is to :

[cell.textLabel setText:
[responseString JSONValue]objectForKey:@"response"] ;

Parse the json value to get your desired output.

Comment: The text has HTML formatted characters in it. Like &#; and &Amul; etc

Comment: Your problem solved ?
Can you add this text to UIWebview,and add subview to cell.
It may work,once i did the same for my html formatted code.

Comment: No..i used Google's HTML attributed string to get them. It was easy!